# return new Node(data) Can anyone tell me what this function actually returning?

Tags: java, binary-tree

```
public static Node insert(Node root, int data) 
    if (root == null) 
        return new Node(data);
```

Comment: This is not valid Java syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a reference to an object of type `Node`. As I can infer from the tags of your question you are dealing with a tree data structure. This method tries to insert a node to a tree. If there isn't any other node in the tree, this is going  to be the root of the tree. Otherwise (`root!=null`) you should implement a way through which you add another (non root node) to a tree.

Answer (score 1):

It returns a "Node" object which is created by a new constructor which accepts an integer (in this case "data").